# Use google maps in Ionic + angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I have a simple contact page on which I have to include a google map with a certain location, but I can't seem to be able to

My clean .html file looks like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar primary>
        <ion-title>Contact</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="contactpage">
    <div id="map"></div>
</ion-contant>
```

My clean .ts file looks like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ApiRequest} from '../../../cck/cck';


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/cck/contact/contact.html',
})
export class Contact {
    private contactPage: Object = {};

    constructor(private navController:NavController, private request: ApiRequest) {
    }
}
```

I would like to add a google map inside the div with the id map, and I've tried several solutions that I've found online but I could not make any of them work

Does anybody have a good demo?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps has a url format that allows you to search for a location, like so:

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=trumptower
```

The easiest way to accomplish your goal is to use the InAppBrowser plugin to open a new InAppBrowser window that goes to a url that you create based off your contact location. The cool thing is that if you have Google Maps installed on your device, the url will open in the Google Maps application.

**HTML:**

```
<button class="button button-full" ng-click="openMaps(contact)">
    Open in Maps
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.openMaps = function (contact) {
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://maps.google.com/?q=' + contact.location, '_system', 'location = yes');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunately I need to show the map on the page itself .. it's a contact page and the people want them to have it right there